# JavaScript Not Adding Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, flexbox

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Youtube Card</title>
        <style>
          .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            width: 900px;
            height: 198px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: black;
          }
          .box {
            height: 190px;
            margin: 4px;
            /* border: 2px solid grey; */
            border-radius: 15px;
          }
          .photo {
            width: 180px;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          .textbox {
            width: 681px;
            color: azure;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
          }
          #img {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          .numberbox {
            height: 17px;
            width: 43px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 7px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            z-index: 5;
            position: relative;
            top: 163px;
            left: 129px;
            font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 500;
          }
          .boxtitle {
            height: 49px;
            width: 702px;
            /* border: 2px solid gray; */
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
            color: white;
            bottom: 12px;
            position: relative;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            line-height: 2.2rem;
            max-height: 4.4rem;
            font-size: 1.6rem;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          }
          .boxdescription {
            height: 99px;
            width: 702px;
            /* border: 2px solid grey; */
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
            color: rgb(152, 147, 147);
            position: relative;
            top: 3px;
          }
          .innerbox {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          }
          .innerboxdot {
            font-weight: 400;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 3px;
            font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="photo box">
            <img
              src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRj_nNfaS6PjY5sGzdvEyn4wrFFrrPl_WSoLQ&usqp=CAU"
              height="190px"
              width="180px"
              id="img"
            />
            <div class="numberbox">Video Time</div>
          </div>
          <div class="textbox box">
            <div class="boxtitle">Title Here</div>
            <div class="boxdescription">
              <div class="innerbox">Channel Name</div>
              <div class="innerboxdot">.</div>
              <div class="innerbox">views</div>
              <div class="innerboxdot">.</div>
              <div class="innerbox">upload time</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        console.log("Running Script"); 
    
        let photo=document.body.children[0].children[0].children[0]
        let video_time=document.body.children[0].children[0].children[1].innerText
        let title=document.body.children[0].lastElementChild.children[0].innerText
        let channel_name=document.body.children[0].children[1].lastElementChild.children[0].innerText
        let views=document.body.children[0].children[1].lastElementChild.children[2].innerText
        let upload_time=document.body.children[0].children[1].lastElementChild.children[4].innerText
        
        console.log("Running Photo");
    
        let user_photo=prompt("Enter The URL Of Image You Want As Thumbnail : \n(If Not Type \"no\")")
        if (user_photo=="no" || user_photo=="No" || user_photo=="NO") {
          document.body.children[0].children[0].children[0].setAttribute("src","https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRj_nNfaS6PjY5sGzdvEyn4wrFFrrPl_WSoLQ&usqp=CAU")
        }
        else{
          document.body.children[0].children[0].children[0].setAttribute("src",user_photo)
        }
        
        console.log(user_photo);
        
        console.log("Running Video Timing");
    
        let user_video_time=prompt("Enter Your Video Timing : \n(Type In The Format hour:minute:second or minute:second")
        video_time=user_video_time
    
        console.log(user_video_time, typeof user_video_time);
        
        console.log("Running Title");
    
        let user_title=prompt("Enter Title OF Your Video : ")
        title=user_title
    
        console.log(user_title);
        
        console.log("Running Channel Name");
    
        let user_channel_name=prompt("Enter Your Channel Name : ")
        channel_name=user_channel_name
    
        console.log(user_channel_name);
        
        console.log("Running Views");
    
        //   let user_views=prompt("Enter Views :\n(Enter In Pure Number)")
        //   if (user_views.length=4 || user_views.length=5 || user_views.length=6) {
        //     views=String(Math.ceil.((Number)user_views/1000))+"K views ";
        //   }
        //   else if (user_views.length=7 || user_views.length=8 || user_views.length=9) {
        //     views=String(Math.ceil.((Number)user_views/1000000))+"M views "
        //   }
        //   else if (user_views.length=10 || user_views.length=11 || user_views.length=12) {
        //     views=String(Math.ceil.((Number)user_views/1000000000))+"B views "
        //   }
        //   else{
        //     views=user_views
        //   }
    
        // console.log(user_views);
        
        console.log("Running Upload Time");
    
        let user_upload_time=prompt("Enter Upload Time : \n(Enter In The Format {Number Month} Or {Number Year})")
        upload_time=user_upload_time+" ago "
    
        console.log(user_upload_time);
    
        console.log("End");
        
        </script>
      </body>
      
    </html>
```

I made this code for custom youtube card. All console.log functions are running but inputs are not getting added like this `video_time=user_video_time`. Also please fix the code in comments (its showing error I dont know why). To run this code, save the given code as html file.

I had tried to change code by using querySelector() but not working. All codes are working in browser console if typed separately.

I made this code for custom youtube card. All console.log functions are running but inputs are not getting added like this `video_time=user_video_time`. Also please fix the code in comments (its showing error I dont know why). To run this code, save the given code as html file.

I had tried to change code by using querySelector() but not working. All codes are working in browser console if typed seperately.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that repeating yourself multiple times helps to clarify your question (perhaps in response to Stack Overflow prompting you for additional information).  It does not, and instead it is often perceived as lazy or even rude and demanding, which is counterproductive to solving your problem.  Please take some time to edit and clarify your question.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If you assign a variable to hold a string, like `let txt = myElement.innerText` a copy of the value is stored in txt.  Changing txt does not change myElement at all.  You can however write to `myElement.innerText` with the updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Script tag, when ever wanted a change to the HTML tags then, get that full element(tags). But here "title" or "channel_name" variables, You are fetching data inside the tags.
so,

title = "Title Here" initially.

Now, you are just assigning your prompt data to that "title" variable. but actually you need to fetch the entire tag.

eg:

```
let title = document.body.children[0].lastElementChild.children[0]
```

now, assign the prompt value to title using

```
title.innerText = user_title
```